# SSPI - disable AES256 algorithm

Tags: c++, ssl, sspi

I want to establish a secure connection using SSPI(Schannel).
I cannot use as AES256 to cipher suite. As I saw [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379810%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I have to define my own algorithms list to disable the AES256 cipher suite, I set the ALG_ID parameter to CALG_RSA_KEYX chiper, but I see in wireshark capture that my application still chooses "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA".

The code snippet below shows how to craete a secure context. This code is taken from [here](http://www.coastrd.com/c-schannel-smtp), and I changed it to take a list of algorithm instead to use the default OS algorithms:

```
TimeStamp        tsExpiry;
SECURITY_STATUS  Status;
DWORD            cSupportedAlgs = 0;
ALG_ID           rgbSupportedAlgs[16];
PCCERT_CONTEXT   pCertContext = NULL;


certEnhkeyUsage.rgpszUsageIdentifier = usages; 

// Build Schannel credential structure. Currently, this sample only
// specifies the protocol to be used (and optionally the certificate, 
// of course). Real applications may wish to specify other parameters as well.
ZeroMemory( &SchannelCred, sizeof(SchannelCred) );

SchannelCred.dwVersion  = SCHANNEL_CRED_VERSION;

SchannelCred.grbitEnabledProtocols = dwProtocol;

rgbSupportedAlgs[0] = CALG_RSA_KEYX;
cSupportedAlgs++;
SchannelCred.cSupportedAlgs    = cSupportedAlgs;
SchannelCred.palgSupportedAlgs = rgbSupportedAlgs;

// Flags indicate the context behaviour.
SchannelCred.dwFlags |= SCH_CRED_NO_DEFAULT_CREDS;
SchannelCred.dwFlags |= SCH_CRED_AUTO_CRED_VALIDATION;


// Create an SSPI credential.
Status = g_pSSPI->AcquireCredentialsHandleA( NULL,                 // Name of principal    
                                             UNISP_NAME_A,         // Name of package
                                             SECPKG_CRED_OUTBOUND, // Flags indicating use
                                             NULL,                 // Pointer to logon ID
                                             &SchannelCred,        // Package specific data
                                             NULL,                 // Pointer to GetKey() func
                                             NULL,                 // Value to pass to GetKey()
                                             phCreds,              // (out) Cred Handle
                                             &tsExpiry );          // (out) Lifetime (optional)

if(Status != SEC_E_OK) printf("**** Error 0x%x returned by AcquireCredentialsHandle\n", Status);

return Status;
```

can someone please explain me why? and what do I have to do in order to disable AES_256?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you think we should know a bit more about what your code does (e.g. by seeing it) in order to explain you why it does what it does? If we would assume that your code does the things exactly as documented, we could probably also assume that it does behave the way it should. Since it does not, it seems to not be doing the things as documented. But how should we point out the point where it does so?

Comment: @PlasmaHH : got it, please see the editing above.